# Flask-Sqlalchemy 3 way many to many relationship

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to create a database for events and event RSVPs...

For each event there should be possible food items for an rsvp to choose from

When a user RSVP's, the rsvp model created for them should contain the food item they chose so far..

this is what I have so far:

```
event_meals = db.Table('event_meals',
                       db.Column('meal_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('meal.id')),
                       db.Column('event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id')))

rsvp_meals = db.Table('rsvp_meals',
                      db.Column('meal_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('meal.id')),
                      db.Column('rsvp_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('rsvp.id')))

class Event(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(256), unique=True)
    date = db.Column(db.String(128))
    photo = db.Column(db.String(256))
    info = db.Column(db.String(1024))
    meals = db.relationship('Meal', secondary='event_meals',
                            backref=db.backref('meals', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title


class Rsvp(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    price = db.Column(db.String(64))
    meals = db.relationship('Meal', secondary='rsvp_meals',
                            backref=db.backref('meals', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


class Meal(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128))
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title
```

Not surprisingly this gives an error:

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'meals' on relationship 'Rsvp.meals': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Meal|meal'

Can anyone help me make this work?! Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`backref` is the name that should be used to expose the many-to-many relationship on the *related* model.  In your case, you are saying that both `Event` and `Rsvp` models should be exposed as the attribute `meals` on the `Meal` model.  In other words, when I have a `Meal` and I want to see who has RSVP'd, I should access the `meals` attribute on the `Meal` instance.  However, you are also declaring that if I want to see what `Event`s the meal is associated with, I should access the `meals` attribute of the meal ... which is why SQLAlchemy throws an error.

What you most likely meant is to expose `rsvps` and `events` on `Meals`:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    # ... snip ...
    meals = db.relationship('Meal', secondary='event_meals',
                            backref=db.backref('events', lazy='dynamic'))

# ... snip ...    

class Rsvp(db.Model):
    # ... snip ...
    meals = db.relationship('Meal', secondary='rsvp_meals',
                            backref=db.backref('rsvps', lazy='dynamic'))
```

Then, for any `Meal` instance you can query its `Event`s and `RSVP`s:

```
for rsvp in Meal.query.get(meal_id).rsvps:
    print rsvp.name
```

The key thing to note is that SQLAlchemy is a very DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) framework.  If you find yourself having to keep names in sync between different parts of the declaration of the same field, you are probably missing an easier way to do things.

Comment: You rock sean!  Great explanation and it worked perfectly.  Thanks man!

Comment: Is this really the best way?  Why wouldn't you make a typical 3way junction table?

Comment: @applewood - it may not be the best way - the question though was about why the OP had the issues it had.  A table of `event_id`, `meal_id`, `rsvp_id` might well make more sense (depending on the use case).

Comment: will the above case work if meal itself appears repeadly. for example meal 1 appears in event 1 and event 2 and rsvp 1 and rsvp 2 had meal 1.

Comment: I tried above command : AttributeError: type object 'Rating' has no attribute 'get' . How do i define get?